# Having an error when using String in Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am trying to create a class implementing comparable. When all the class elements are integer, everything works well. When I go with String and use `comparing` rather than `comparingInt`, I receive the following errors.

- Incorrect number of type arguments for generic method comparing(Function) of type Comparator; it cannot be parameterized with arguments
- The type myClassdoes not define getFrom(T) that is applicable here

```
public class myClass implements Comparable<myClass> {
    @Column (name="From")
    private String from;
    @Column (name="To")
    private String to;
    @Column (name="With")
    private String with;
    @Column (name="amount")
    private int amount;

    // Setters, getters, constructor

    Comparator<myClass > comp = Comparator.<myClass>comparing(myClass::getFrom)
            .thenComparing(myClass::getTo)
            .thenComparing(myClass::getWith)
            .thenComparingInt(myClass::getAmount);
    @Override
    public int compareTo(myClass o) {
        return comp.compare(this, o);
    }
}
```

Could someone point out what I might be missing here?

Comment: remove the generic type and it should work or explicitly `Comparator.<myClass, String>comparing`...

Comment: @michalk when I explicitly wrote it, it worked. Could you please explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comparator::comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) is a generic method that takes a function that is used to extract the value to be compared. You passed a method reference to `myClass::getFrom` method which returns a `String` and will be invoked on `myClass` type object (through `Function::apply`). That is why you have to pass generic types `myClass` and `String`.

However you could ommit those generic types because you are assigning your comparator to `Comparator<myClass> comp` variable so types can be inferred automatically (also using types from your method reference used).

Looking further let's look at `Comparator::comparing(Function)` method implementation :

```
static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> var0) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(var0);
    return (Comparator)((Serializable)((var1x, var2x) -> {
        return ((Comparable)var0.apply(var1x)).compareTo(var0.apply(var2x));
    }));
}
```

Here `T` will be `myClass` and `U` will be `String`. Function `var0` will take `myClass` as parameter and will return `String` (so method reference to `myClass::getFrom` will work here - generally it will be like invoking `getFrom` on `myClass` object). Actually as you can see this method will return a `Comparator` as a lambda function which will use function `var0` to extract values from `var1x` and `var2x` (both of them will be `myClass` types). For me it looks a bit like a closure.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, a few things here.  First of all, here's working code which mostly just removes the type arguments you provided.

You can do this because they will be automatically inferred.  You only have to do it explicitly when they aren't inferrable (which your IDE will tell you).  There is plenty of info on type inference scattered around the Java docs; e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>{
    private String from;
    private String to;

    public String getFrom() { return from; }
    public String getTo() { return to; }

    Comparator<MyClass> comp = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getFrom)
            .thenComparing(MyClass::getTo);

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass o) {
        return comp.compare(this, o);
    }
}
```

Some other notes that are helpful in general or for SO for future reference:

- Upper case first letter in class name.
- Try to strip down your code to a full/reproducible example.  For example, this uses 2 fields both of which exist and can be pasted into an IDE.  The question one uses 4 fields most of which aren't present.